# How to code a non-uniform random distribution in PHP

Tags: php, random

I'm new there :)
I was trying to create a non-uniform random distribution code in PHP with following probabilities in decimals (precision 2)

```
From 1.10 to 1.15 = 40%
From 1.16 to 1.20 = 30%
From 1.21 to 1.25 = 20%
From 1.26 to 1.30 = 10%
```

That's my actual code:

```
$low = 1.1
$high = 1.3
$multiplier = mt_rand($low*100,$high*100)/100;
```

This doesn't return the desired distribution. How can I change my code to make it not uniform in distribution?

Comment: Not really clear what do you want. I assume you want that numbers from different range have different chances of occuring?

Comment: @supermoney Please don't edit your question to replace it with an answer.

Comment: @supermoney I've edited your title and question with the correct statistical definition: you're looking for a non-unifor random distribution. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Get a 1-100 random number to decide in which range it will be (40%,30%,20%,10%)
2. Calculate your random float depending on the percentage range

```
$chance = rand(1,100);
switch(true) {
    case ($chance <= 40):
        // 40% 1.10 - 1.15
        echo 1+rand(10,15)/100;
        break;
    case ($chance <= 70):
        // 30% 1.16 - 1.20
        echo 1+rand(16,20)/100;
        break;
    case ($chance <= 90):
        // 20% 1.21 - 1.25
        echo 1+rand(21,25)/100;
        break;
    default:
        // 10% 1.26 - 1.30
        echo 1+rand(26,30)/100;
        break;
}
```

Run it 10'000'000 times, gives the following percentages:

```
From 1.10 to 1.15 = 40.00223%
From 1.16 to 1.20 = 29.99841%
From 1.21 to 1.25 = 20.00157%
From 1.26 to 1.30 = 9.99779%
```

**Update:** Updated as icio recommended

Comment: You'll get better runtime performance if you check for the bigger buckets first: `$chance <= 40`, `$chance <= 70`, etc... because you're less likely to have to check subsequent steps with each iteration.

Comment: Oh, thats correct. Tested it again, improved the performance by 2% :)

Comment: If this helped you, closing the question would help keeping stackoverflow cleaned up and others to find the question later :-)

Comment: @Marc not closing the question, but rather accepting the answer. Anyway, it's a good custom to not accept any answer in the first 24 hours.

Comment: Yeah, but this is 3 days old :-) and according to his comment, this seems to be answered

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the date until now. I'm at the end of the workday, forgive me.

Comment: I've accepted the answer but I don't understand how to close the question itself!

Comment: Sorry, "closing" was formulated incorrectly. I meant accept :-)